# Lambda Consumer if-statement

Tags: java, lambda

I'm having problems of in Java in writing a Lambda Consumer if statement correctly. The consumer should work so that if the object Teos is null or the method getNimi returns "" it changes the name with setNimi to "nimi ei tiedossa". This is homework, so I'm supposed to write the Lambda as a parameter, not in the method itself.

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> {
       if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null) {    
          teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa")
       }
   };
);
```

How should the if statement be written?

NetBeans error-message says ; expected, ) expected and illegal start of expression, but I can't find the correct spots for ; and ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm supposed to write the Lambda as a parameter, not in the method itself"? Do you mean that you need to create your lambda separately, as an instance of `Consumer`, and then write something like `kokoelma.muuta(myLambda);`?

Answer (score 2):

Try expanding it out.

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> {if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null) teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa")};);
```

This becomes:

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> {
    if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null)
        teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa")
};
);
```

From here it's clear the semicolon should be after the statement, and there shouldn't be one after the lambda:

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> {
    if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null)
        teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa");
}
);
```

Or, shortened again:

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> { if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null) teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa");});
```

Comment: Great answer! I would rather stick with the non-shortened lamba for this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, I tried breaking it down, but didn't spot the error. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a more complex `lambda`, you should break it in multiple rows.
If you do this, it will be clear where you did wrong:

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> {
    if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null)
        teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa")
    };
);
```

A more short version of a lambda, that can only hold one statement, has no semi-colons and disposes the `{` and `}`:

```
kokoelma.muuta(teos -> if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null) teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa"));
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Its more of understanding about how consumers work in java8.
Its any function which takes the type and does some operation without returning anything.

 
Sorry I don't know what muuta is but it looks like some kind of iteration over iterable kokoelma.

For this you can have a exclusive Consumer defined and pass it to muuta.

for example

```
    public static class Something{
    String nimi;

    public String getNimi() {
        return nimi;
    }

    public void setNimi(String nimi) {
        this.nimi = nimi;
    }
}
```

Then we can create a consumer and pass it as a function .

```
    List<Something> kokoelma = new ArrayList<>();

   Consumer<Something> checkAndSet = 
            teos -> {
                if (teos.getNimi().equals("") || teos.getNimi() != null)
                    teos.setNimi("nimi ei tiedossa");
            };

    kokoelma.forEach(checkAndSet);
```